# Enzyme Cannot Find Component / <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, css-selectors, enzyme

I am using "react": "^15.5.4" and "enzyme": "^2.8.2"

Given the following output from `wrapper.debug()`:

```
<CellRenderer idx={4} rowIdx={0} height={35} column={{...}} 
              cellMetaData={{...}} value={3} rowData={{...}} 
              isRowSelected={false} expandableOptions={{...}}
              selectedColumn={[undefined]} formatter={[undefined]} 
              isScrolling={true}>
                                    
              <Cell idx={4} rowIdx={0} height={35} column={{...}}
                    cellMetaData={{...}} value={3} rowData={{...}}
                    isRowSelected={false} expandableOptions={{...}} 
                    selectedColumn={[undefined]} formatter={[undefined]} 
                    isScrolling={true} className="" tooltip=""
                    tabIndex={-1} isExpanded={false} isCellValueChanging={[Function]}>
                                    
                    <div height={35} tabIndex={-1} value={3} className="react-grid-Cell" 
                         style={{...}} onClick={[Function]} onDoubleClick={[Function]} 
                         onContextMenu={[Function]} onDragOver={[Function]}>
                                    
                         <div className="react-grid-Cell__value">
                              <div style={{...}}>
                                   <span>
                                         <SimpleCellFormatter value={3}>
                                                <div title={3}>
                                                  3
                                                </div>
```

I cannot find any of the elements I need using:

- `wrapper.find(wrapper.findWhere(n => n.name() === 'CellRenderer'))`
- `wrapper.find("div[title='3']"`
- `wrapper.find("div[value='3']")`

  Any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

`wrapper.find('CellRenderer')
wrapper.find('div').findWhere(d => d.prop('title') === 3)
wrapper.find('div').findWhere(d => d.prop('value') === 3)`

Comment: Thanks! It works! Do you have any idea by a chance why I cannot access the element directly with the selector and go through find(..).findWhere(..)?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I guess it is because you have a `Cell` and `SimpleCellFormatter` and probably enzyme works fine with CSS selectors if you have a clear HTML tree. Once you start mixing React elements with HTML ones becomes tricky.

Comment: It is a mystery for me. Because it some cases it works just fine. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `title` and `value` attributes you pass in are number, not string.
So the right way is

```
wrapper.find('div[title=3]')
wrapper.find('div[value=3]')
```

On the other hand, if your JSX is

```
<div title="3"></div>
```

Then you can do

```
wrapper.find('div[title="3"]')
```

This is mentioned in the [docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#1-a-valid-css-selector).